# Ember: How to render a template

Tags: ember.js

How to render a certain template by name? Supposed that I have a button, on button clicked event I want to show that template in a modal. Can you guys please guide me.

Comment: The correct way to do that is to have a component with the template that you need, and to show that in a modal.

Comment: There is also great [addon](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-modal-dialog) to help with modals.

Comment: Always remember what a model is: a div!, and another big div is shadowing everything else. Just use a component and a `{{#if}}` helper to show/hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it´s officially deprecated (still working but no longer in documentation @2.3) but you can render any template into an outlet from within a route https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/routing/rendering-a-template/

```
// .../app/routes/your route
self.render('templatename', {
    into: 'parent template which contains the outlet',
    outlet: 'outletname',
    controller: controller for the template //optional!
});
```

My modals look like this

```
<div class="modal fade modal-overflow in" id="panel-delete-item" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            {{outlet 'delete_item'}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```